# SMBus on PCIe Slot

Tags: x86, kernel, pci-e, smbus

I have some PCIe cards, which have some PMICs on SMBus.

If I connect more than one (identical) PCIe cards on different slots(on an x86), would I be able too access all PMICs (with same address)?

Does all the PCIe slots share the same SMBus lines, so that no more than one device with the same slave address can be connected on the PCIe slots?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is depend on your driver code. If you share same memory spaces to both PCIe cards, they can share same memory spaces which is located in the host system.